# How to install python-affinity package on Debian?

Tags: python, module, affinity

I hope this is the correct place instead of Unix User of Stack Overflow etc;

How do I install the Python package [affinity](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/affinity) on Debian Squeeze?

I have downloaded the tar, unpacked it, and ran the following command but it fails; I have never insall a python module like this before so I'm lost :)

```
root@host:~/affinity-0.1.0# python setup.py install
running install
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing affinity.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to affinity.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to affinity.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'affinity.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'affinity.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/affinity
copying affinity/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/affinity
running build_ext
building 'affinity._affinity' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/affinity
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c affinity/_affinity.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/affinity/_affinity.o
affinity/_affinity.c:14:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
affinity/_affinity.c:17: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
affinity/_affinity.c:19: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
affinity/_affinity.c:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
affinity/_affinity.c:63: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘methods’
affinity/_affinity.c:80: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘init_affinity’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, fixed it. I see now that I have just installed the package `python` and not additionally `python-dev`, which is required for header files as indicated in my question output by this line:

```
affinity/_affinity.c:14:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```